# Eric IDE: running unit tests inside IDE

Tags: python-unittest, eric-ide

I've got a small project and running unit tests:

```
$ python tests/runner.py 
......
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.002s
OK
$ python -m tests.runner
......
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.002s
OK
```

`tests/runner.py`:

```
import unittest

loader = unittest.TestLoader()
tests = loader.discover('.')
testRunner = unittest.runner.TextTestRunner()
testRunner.run(tests)
```

`tests/test_common.py` (a single test case, nothing else):

```
from procr.core.pcp import *  # pcp - module under test.

class TestHelpers(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_something(self):
    ...
```

Directory structure:

```
project/
  __init__.py
  procr/
    core/
      __init__.py
      pcp.py
    __init__.py
  tests/
    __init__.py
    test_common.py
    runner.py
```

Eric IDE requires a test, or test suite file. Supplied with `runner.py` it reports `Error: suite(unittest.loader._FailedTest)`. Project directory is set to `project`, full path.

What can be possibly wrong?

UPD:

The tests even actually run, as shown in the Eric console. The IDE probably expects something a bit different from the runner. I've no idea what.

Comment: `tests = loader.discover('.')`, Is this dot current directory causing issue? you did not mention where `eric` is located.

Comment: Eric project directory is correct: it's the same as the directory from which the shell examples are successfully running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no Eric Unittest Manual, not by any means. Yet it is better than nothing. At least a small step forward.

A soft link to `tests/test_common.py` (otherwise the working directory shifts from the `project`):

```
project/
  __init__.py
  procr/
    core/
      __init__.py
      pcp.py
    __init__.py
  tests/
    __init__.py
    test_common.py
    runner.py

  eric_test_common.py -> tests/test_common.py
```

Eric Unittest Dialog:

- `Enter test filename`: full path to `eric_test_common.py`
- `Enter test name`: `TestHelpers`
- `Run local`: check
- `Start`: push

It's just the first working option I discovered; there must be much more. I hope to make this answer better in time.

[Eric Unittest Dialog on GitHub](https://github.com/pycom/EricShort/blob/master/PyUnit/UnittestDialog.py)